# MySQL views with arguments

Tags: mysql

I have been working on a pretty large database this last week. Basically I am taking an Access database and converting it to a MySQL database. I have seccessfully converted all the tables and views to MySQL. However I have a view that requires input from the user, the date. The other view is the view that will be call.

view 1 - `compiled_fourweeks` - needs date
view 2 - `metrics_fourweeks` - uses `compiled_fourweeks in query.

I was thinking of a precedure but I won't be able to reference the columns in the query.

I am kind of running out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You need a query that, when executed, calls data from another query that requires user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to execute a view (`metrics_fourweeks`) that needs data from another view (`compiled_fourweeks`), and this last view requires input from the user.

I would go with the procedure approach:

```
create procedure fourWeeksData(d date)
    create or replace view compiled_fourweeks
        select ... 
        from ...   
        where recordDate = f  -- Just an example; use whichever where clause you need
        ...;

    select * from metrics_fourweeks;
end
```

If your database will be used just by a single user, your problem is solved. But if your database is meant to be used by more than one user... well, you can use temporary tables:

```
create procedure fourWeeksData2(d date)
    drop table if exists temp_compiled_fourweeks;
    create temporary table temp_compiled_fourweeks
        select ... 
        from ...   
        where recordDate = f  -- Just an example; use whichever where clause you need
        ...;
    -- You will need to create the required indexes for this new temp table

    -- Now replicate the SQL statement, using your new temp table
    select ... 
    from temp_compiled_fourweeks
    ...;
end
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: FYI a view cannot have a variable, I tried that last night and it wouldn't let me. On the bright side the temp table worked out great, downside I have to figure the best way to index the temp table. This increased my query time from 2~ sec to 5~ :(

Comment: @BrandonWilson Well... "No free lunch"... An yes, you're right about the variable, sorry about that... but anyway, the *temporary table* solution is the best approach, since the data can be available for every single connection (remember: temp tables belong to a connection, and are deleted when the connection is closed or killed).